# How to quote string with backtick in zsh?

Tags: zsh, quoting

I need to mount an SMB share with a line like

`mount_smbfs //username:password@server.com/folder/ mountpoint`

But my `password` contains backticks!

How would I quote this?

I've tried:

```
mount_smbfs //username:\`123\`123@server.com/folder/ mountpoint
```

And single quotes:

```
mount_smbfs '//username:`123`123@server.com/folder/' mountpoint
```

And a variable:

```
pw='`123`123'
mount_smbfs //username:$pw@server.com/folder/ mountpoint
```

All of which give me

`mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument`

Comment: Wrap them in single quotes? `'`?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an issue with the argument itself, but rather a missing argument.

Comment: You haven't supplied the local filesystem path where the remote file system should be mounted.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include mountpoint. Edited question. Still doesn't work.

Comment: If Zsh would interpret your backtits, you would get something like _ .... 123 ... command not found _ as error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do any string that contains characters that need to be escaped:

```
mount_smbfs //username:my\`password@server.com/folder/
```

or

```
mount_smbfs '//username:my`password@server.com/folder/'
```

You can't use double quotes alone, because the backtick in a double-quoted string is interpreted as the start of a command substitution. You could write

```
mount_smbfs "//username:my\`password@server.com/folder/"
```

---

Based on the error message, the problem isn't protecting the backtick from the shell, but from the URL parsing library. Try

```
mount_smbfs '//username:%60123%60123@server.com/folder/' mountpoint
```

where `%60` is the URL-quoted form for a backtick. Quoting the URL anyway is good practice: don't expose anything you don't want processed to the shell, even if you are sure there's nothing that the shell *would* process.

Comment: Tried all that, failed ... updated question.

Comment: Is there a command line function to 'url quote' any string?